# How to block a Dart app from moving forward when there is a lot of data to pull from IndexedDB and all you get is Futures?

Tags: dart, indexeddb, dart-async

I tried migrating my app from using localStorage to using indexedDB (via Lawndart). The use of Futures now are messing with my head! Effectively what I want to do is this: When a user wants to load a saved game, block the app from proceeding until all the data is loaded from indexedDB. This isn't a matter of "displaying the weather while stock quotes load..." as seems to be a lot of the examples. I need all the data before I can even render anything.

Before I gave up and put in a required click in my app as a hacky means to wait for the futures to complete, I wanted do the following (using Lawndart as my interface to indexedDb) and just couldn't wrap my head around the *right* way to do it.

1. Load a saved game state.
2. Load the saved player data from the game (300 players)
3. Load the saved tournament data from the game (40+ tournaments, loading and creating an object one-by-one, also tried in bulk with a stream.)
4. Refresh the DOM with the tournament display from the saved state.

However #4 would always try to happen before #3 would complete and throw an error because one of the tournaments it's trying to render in the DOM is not fully loaded from the loop yet.

I wanted to try the new async/await stuff (would that solve this?) but I would also really like to know how I could accomplish the above with futures/completes/etc/etc since it's driving me crazy.
Here's the loadGame function I ended up with:

```dart
loadGame(String _id)  {

  if(_id == null) _id="a";

  String _prefix;
  if(_id == "a") {
    _prefix = "a";
  } else {
    _prefix = _savedGames[_id];
  }

  String loadedGame;
  // total # of players to load from indexedDb
  int numPlayers;

   // load saved game basics
  _gameStore.getByKey(_prefix+"_game").then((loadedGame) {

    Map saveObject = JSON.decode(loadedGame);
    _year = int.parse(saveObject["year"]);
    _week = int.parse(saveObject["week"]);
    _numWeeks = int.parse(saveObject["numweeks"]);
    numPlayers = int.parse(saveObject["numplayers"]);


  }).then((_) {
    // load the stored players
    _players = new Map<int, Player>();
    for(int i=1; i<numPlayers+1; i++) {
       //note that this would go 1-by-1 loading players from indexedDb
       // essentially using the Lawndart store.getByKey(_id) for each one
       Player.loadFromDatabase(_prefix+"_player_"+i.toString());
    }


  }).then((_) {
      // load the stored tournaments
      _tournaments = new Map<int, Tournament>();
     List<String> tournamentKeys;
     for(int i=1; i<_numWeeks+1; i++) {
      // this hits the database for each item
      // same as for players.
      // how can I ensure that all these are done before going on to next thing
      // when each request to the database sends me a future?
      Tournament.loadFromDatabase(_prefix+"_tournament_"+i.toString());
     }


  }).then((_) {
    // just hides a message in the dom
    hideStatus();
  }).then((_) {
    // this modifies the dom and shows the game status
    // needs to wait till all the tournaments are loaded though or it gives me 
    // null pointer exceptions because the tournament it's trying to render isn't loaded yet.
    nextWeek();
  });
}
```

Comment: It's funny how simple and straightforward this would be using plain continuations (callback functions) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past, don't know if this is the best way to do it but it seems to work :-

```dart
List<Future> updateList = new List<Future>();
  for(int i=1; i<_numWeeks+1; i++) {
  updateList.add(Tournament.loadFromDatabase("${_prefix}${_tournament_}$i"));
}
Future.wait(updateList)..then((_) {...................
```

So you get all your futures into a List and wait for them all to complete before moving on.

Answer (score 1):

When you chain `Future`s you have to return the `Future` in your `then` method.

For instance, assuming `Player.loadFromDatabase` returns `Future` you should write:

```dart
  }).then((_) {
    final futures = <Future>[];

    // load the stored players
    _players = new Map<int, Player>();
    for(int i=1; i<numPlayers+1; i++) {
       futures.add(Player.loadFromDatabase(_prefix+"_player_"+i.toString()));
    }

    return Future.wait(futures);
  }).then((_) {
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick and between your reply and the last 2 days of searching for an answer I think it all finally clicks with me. Appreciate your help!